# Postiton an echo on the page in PHP or incorporate it with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I have a website with my multiple pages, on each of my pages I am using CSS to display a header with the users username and a logout feature. Although on one page my header is pushed to the bottom as I am echoing out a table from my database. The table echos to the top of the screen, pushing my header below it. Can anyone explain to me how to position the echo on the page in the middle of the screen, or move the echo to be a part of the html. Here is the code for my page

Thank You

```
  <?php  
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
//maintain SESSION user_id

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);



//Select video name and question

$query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

$enisatquestion = "<table >";

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {


    $enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td></tr>";

}

$enisatquestion .= "</table>";    

echo $enisatquestion;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Give `id` or `class` to give styling to your PHP generated element. **Eg:** `$enisatquestion .= "<table class='someName'>";`. Now for your **CSS:** `.someClass {properties:values)`.

Comment: use `<?php echo $enisatquestion;?>` inside your body tag and not at the top of  your html tags

Comment: that simply is not valid - you cannot output content outside of the html tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outputting html content outside of the `<html></html>` tags will produce invalid markup - technically it will render within the browser but will be unaffected by css and the general document flow - please don't do it.

For your case, use php before the html to do the recordset selections if needs be but save outputting the generated html until it is needed within the document body as below.

```
<?php  

    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) header("Location: index.php");

    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array( $res );

    $query = "SELECT eNISATQuestion, eNISATVideo FROM enisatquestion";

    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    /* A default message if the query fails or there are no records */
    $enisatquestion='<h2>Sorry, there are no records</h2>';


    /* you cannot output content outside the html tags, not valid ~ it will work but NO */
    if( $result ) {/* if there is a recordset, proceed and generate html table */
        $enisatquestion = "<table >";
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $enisatquestion .= "<tr><td><a href='{$row['eNISATVideo']}'>{$row['eNISATQuestion']}</a></td></tr>";
        }
        $enisatquestion .= "</table>";    
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        /* output the html table here, below your header */
        echo $enisatquestion;
        /*
            If the query failed then the default gets displayed
        */
    ?>  
</div> 
</body>  
</html>
```